# Users are getting an error : Salesforce Error. Sales log API unexpected error in Open CTI

Tags: cti

Users are getting an error when creating a lead using open CTI.

**Users are getting an error:**

> Salesforce Error. Sales log API unexpected error in Open CTI

Answer (score 0):

saveLog errors can happen for various reasons.  Specifically, you aren't providing a required field or you're providing an invalid field or the entity has data constraints that you're not satisfying.

I always start by checking to see if I can manually create a record setting the same fields manually.

Assuming so, another option is to perform the same saveLog() using the Lightning Open CTI vs. Classic Open CTI.  Lightning provides better error responses to saveLog.